# Can Windows 10 Evaluation be rearmed?

Tags: windows, windows-activation

The Windows Server 2012 R2 Evaluation edition had the feature of being able to be rearmed with the following command:

```
slmgr /rearm
```

This would give you 10 more days to use the machine, and could be done 4 or 5 times as needed, to gain another 10 days each time.

I installed Windows 10 Enterprise Evaluation, and ran the same command. However, upon reboot, the evaluation does not seem to want to be activated again.

slmgr /dlv reports that the grace period has expired. Attempting to manually activate windows gives an error code stating that the grace period has expired.

Are the Windows 10 Evals not rearmable to regain grace days at all?

The reason I'd like to do these rearms is so that I could make an image for machines that could be used in something similar to a lab environment for a week.

Answer (score 2):

It works! I'm not sure about the old version and builds, but rearm works flawlessly on the version 1607, build 14393.693

```
slmgr.vbs -rearm
```

Comment: Seems to have worked for my Win10 1909 eval. version VM ("WinDev2001Eval" from Jan. 2020). After a restart, `slmgr -xpr` says it will expire in Jan. 2021.

Answer (score 1):

You can - up to 90 days.  It appears to work on Enterprise - especially if you have downloaded a slightly older DEV Image from Microsoft - for a starting point.  I expect the same rules apply that you can only do so a certain number of times, but it is a good starting point if you want to reliably play around with a complete VS2015 setup - as "blessed" by MS.

We plan to just re-license the images using our corporate keys, but then just reload a new image from MS every 6 months.  This forces us DEVs to make sure we can use the latest tools, but NEVER store any source on the dev machines.

Answer (score 0):

No you can not rearm apparently for Windows 10 Trial edition:

http://forums.windowscentral.com/windows-10/378203-%5Bsolved%5D-possible-rearm.html

You should have 90-days (per microsoft account trial download).
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/evalcenter/evaluate-windows-10-enterprise

Comment: Your link is dead.